# Find out if Twitter Bootstrap checkbox button has been clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to AngularJS and could really use some help. I have a button that's shown below that is part of a form. I need to show a modal when the form is submitted if the button is not clicked. How can I perform this check? I have tried several things with no luck.

```
<button ng-repeat="car in cars" btn-checkbox-false
        class="btn btn-default btn-block text-left"
        ng-click="AddRemoveCar(cars)">
    <i ng-show="carInStock(cars)"
       class="fa fa-check pull-right btn-success btn btn-xs" />
    <i ng-show="!carInStock(cars)"
       class="fa fa-plus pull-right btn-warning btn btn-xs" />
    {{car.Model}}
</button>
```

Comment: *"I need to show a modal when the form is submitted if the button is not clicked."*  I have no clue what that means

Comment: The modal is a reminder to the user that the button has not been clicked. It's not required but the user should be made aware.

Comment: So onsubmit of the form do some sort of validation. So somehow you need to keep track of what was clicked and determine if something was clicked on the submission. It is also weird you are not just using checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So what is hard about it? Add a submit handler, check that something was clicked. If not show the modal. If yes, let the form submit.

Comment: I did not design this initially. I agree check boxes would have been a better choice. But this is what I am working with.

Comment: I could really use a example of how to perform that check.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the UI-Bootstrap `uib-btn-checkbox` directive for your Twitter Bootstrap checkboxes.

The `uib-btn-checkbox` directive, makes a group of Twitter Bootstrap buttons behave like a set of checkboxes.

Then your submit function can check the state of the model as bound with the `ng-model` directive.

For more information, see

- [UI-Bootstrap API Reference - Buttons](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!buttons)

---

### The DEMO<sup>[1](https://plnkr.co/edit/5SaXVy80JoWDgd1w55GL?p=preview)</sup>

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ButtonsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.checkModel = {
    left: false,
    middle: true,
    right: false
  };
  $scope.$watchCollection('checkModel', function () {
    $scope.checkResults = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.checkModel, function (value, key) {
      if (value) {
        $scope.checkResults.push(key);
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
    <h4>Checkbox</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{checkModel}}</pre>
    <pre>Results: {{checkResults}}</pre>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left" 
               uib-btn-checkbox>Left</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle"
               uib-btn-checkbox>Middle</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right"
               uib-btn-checkbox>Right</label>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would be setting up some flag on the button click and check that value on form submit.

In my controller define a variable like `btnClickedFlag = false;`

In Button click function:

```
AddRemoveCar(cars) => {
   this.btnClickedFlag = true;
}
```

Now on form submit , you can just check if `btnClickedFlag` is `true` if not display your modal/dialogue/overlay on screen.

Comment: and why the downvote? It would be better if you care to put a few words while downvoting.